# Share extension with custom class instead of SLComposeServiceViewController

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-share-extension, share-extension

I'm currently working with share extension feature.

here when I search lot, seems always using SLComposeServiceViewController to share the image with some text content to particular app.

But I'm expect custom UIViewController class loaded with selected image from photos app where ever it is like same as the mail composer when open `mail extension on share sheet`

So I got this sample and I followed the instructions which is on this source from the below git hub link (2nd one):

- https://martinnormark.com/present-ios-8-share-extension-as-modal-view/
- https://github.com/martinnormark/ShareByMail

Yes it's seems `4 years ago` so migration and converted to `Swift 4.1` version. After I modified those changes and debug it. It's not working like on the GitHub gif. Yes when initial time, I can present and dismiss a controller when I touch extension app on share sheet. But after I dismissed and again tried to present it, this time it's not reacted on the GitHub gif.

Martin only show and hide the `self.view of UINavigationController Y position value`. Once I pressed the `Cancel or save` bar buttons, then I tried to open it touch by extension on share sheet, it's not working and no reaction there.

Here is the source for `NSExtensionPrincipalClass - EntryViewController`

```
import UIKit  

@objc(EntryViewController)


class EntryViewController : UINavigationController {

init() {
    super.init(rootViewController: ShareViewController())
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }, completion: nil)
}
}

import UIKit
import Social

class ShareViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = .white
    self.navigationItem.title = "Share this"

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(self.cancelButtonTapped(_:)))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .save, target: self, action: #selector(self.saveButtonTapped(_:)))
}

@objc func saveButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.hideExtensionWithCompletionHandler(completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
        self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: nil, completionHandler: nil)
    })
}

@objc func cancelButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.hideExtensionWithCompletionHandler(completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
        self.extensionContext!.cancelRequest(withError: NSError())
    })
}

func hideExtensionWithCompletionHandler(completion:(Bool) -> Void) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.20, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.navigationController!.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.navigationController!.view.frame.size.height)
    }, completion: nil)
}
}
```

How to find and fix issues on the above attempt or how to do custom UIViewController layout instead of using `SLComposeServiceViewController`?

Comment: Why you Use 'UINavigationController' ?
is there any push from 'ShareViewController'?

Comment: @KaushikMakwana I followed the instruction on this link - https://martinnormark.com/present-ios-8-share-extension-as-modal-view/
You can check the reason for using `UINavigationController`  under this text **Fake the modal presentation**

Comment: There is no need to use 'UINavigationController', you can directly use 'ShareViewController' its easy for you, and whatever layout you want design it on storyboard.

Comment: @KaushikMakwana why `storyboard` ? it's not possible to design custom layout  on programmatically ?

Comment: Yes you can design it programmatically also

Answer (score 1):

On your view controller (Button action method)

#### Objective C

Call this when you complete your process

```
[self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:@[] completionHandler:nil];
```

Call this when you/user cancel your process

```
NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSCocoaErrorDomain code:NSUserCancelledError userInfo:nil];
[self.extensionContext cancelRequestWithError:error];
```

#### Swift

Call this when you complete your process

```
self.extensionContext?.completeRequestReturningItems([], completionHandler:nil)
```

Call this when you/user cancel your process

```
let cancelError = NSError(domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain, code: NSUserCancelledError, userInfo: nil)
self.extensionContext!.cancelRequestWithError(cancelError)
```

If you have any API error

```
self.extensionContext!.cancelRequestWithError(error as NSError)
```

#### Update

On your code, you didn't call the completion handler at this method `hideExtensionWithCompletionHandler`

```
func hideExtensionWithCompletionHandler(completion:@escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.20, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.navigationController!.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.navigationController!.view.frame.size.height)
    }, completion: { (_) -> Void in
        completion(true)
    })
}
```